Followup for proof of scalar multiplication of limits
In a previous question of the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ proof of the scalar multiplication property of limits, they say that $\delta$ is $\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$ - but why is $c$ absolute? Sorry, quite confused about this.

argh! how do I make Mathjax markup render?!?

You enclose MathJax notation in single dollar signs for an in-string inclusion, or double dollar signs for a full-up notation.

Sorry for the late comment. Now, the reason absolute value of $c$ is used is to make sure that $\varepsilon/|c|$ is a positive number, since this is a positive number divided by a positive number. If we used $\varepsilon/c$ and $c$ happed to be a negative scalar, then $\varepsilon /c$ would be a negative number

OK, I worked it out. $c$ is an magnitude, so it shouldn't be signed.
Edit: another editor wrote:

Sorry for the late comment. Now, the reason absolute value of $$
is used is to make sure that $/||$ is a positive number, since this is a positive number divided by a positive number. If we used $/$ and $$  happed to be a negative scalar, then $/$ would be a negative number


Glad you could answer your own question. You should either accept the answer or delete both question and answer, so the question does not remain on the unanswered queue.
